# grapesjs-preset-webpage: Cannot use namespace 'Editor' as a type

Tags: angular, typescript, email-templates, grapesjs

i'm about to use grapesjs preset webpage, worked as per the [guide](https://grapesjs.com/docs/#what-is-grapesjs), and installed the plugin **grapesjs-preset-webpage** and added the style and scripts in angular.json file, without plugin the code is working fine with base blocks and panels, when using the preset webpage plug in it throws an error (image attached) & "@angular/cli": "~15.0.4",.

**web-builder.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';
import 'grapesjs-preset-webpage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-web-builder',
  templateUrl: './web-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web-builder.component.scss']
})
export class WebBuilderComponent implements OnInit {

  private _editor: any;

  get editor(){
    return this._editor;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._editor = this.initializeEditor();
    this.editor.on('asset:add', () => {
      console.log('Asset add fired');
      // this.editor.runCommand('open-assets');
    });
  }

  initializeEditor(){
    console.dir(window);
    return grapesjs.init({
      container: '#gjs',
      autorender: true,
      forceClass: false,
      components: '',
      style: '',
      plugins: ['gjs-preset-webpage'],
      pluginsOpts: {
        'gjs-preset-webpage': {
          navbarOpts: false,
          countdownOpts: false,
          formsOpts: false,
          blocksBasicOpts: {
            blocks: ['link-block', 'quote', 'image', 'video', 'text', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
            flexGrid: false,
            stylePrefix: 'lala-'
          }
        }
      },
      assetManager: {
        uploadText: 'Add image through link or upload image',
        modalTitle: 'Select Image',
        openAssetsOnDrop: 1,
        inputPlaceholder: 'http://url/to/the/image.jpg',
        addBtnText: 'Add image',
        uploadFile: (e: any) => {
          const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
        },
        handleAdd: (textFromInput: any) => {
          this.editor.AssetManager.add(textFromInput);
        }
      },
      canvas: {
        styles: [
          'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
        ],
        scripts: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js']
      }
    });

  }


}
```

**web-builder.component.html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="gjs">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i did `npm install grapesjs-preset-webpage`

but i'm receiving below error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

grapesjs-preset-webpage not working for angular/cli  > 11, so created my own.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).